# NSUnknownKeyException on a model variable

Tags: firebase, swift3

'[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key text.'

I'm getting an NSUnknownKeyException at the text variable of my Message model when I attempt to access it in my second tableView() function (at the end of this code). I am still pretty new to swift and don't know how to resolve this. Through my google searches, I found that it could be something to do with storyboards, but I've actually opted to create my UI programmatically so I'm not sure how that could be causing this.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "chat", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleChat))

        observeMessages()
    }

    @objc func handleChat() {
        let chatController = ChatController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
        navigationController?.pushViewController(chatController, animated: true)

        //present(chatController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    var messages = [Message]()

    func observeMessages() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("FalconsVPackers").child("messages")
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let message = Message()
                message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.messages.append(message)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "called")

        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = message.text

        return cell
    }
}
```

My Message model is very simple...

```
import UIKit

class Message: NSObject {

    var text: String?

}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `NSKeyValueCoding` to populate `Message` object so you must add `@objc` to `text` property.

```
message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) // NSKeyValueCoding
```

.

```
class Message : NSObject {
    @objc var text: String?
}
```

If you just want to populate your message object, better just use properties directly instead of `setValuesForKeys`. And in this case you don't have to use `@objc` too.

```
let message = Message()
message.text = dictionary["text"]
```

Comment: Oh, wow. That was an easy fix. Why do I need to add that exactly so that I can avoid this situation in the future? Thank you so much!